# Installer is getting failed while running post install script

Tags: terminal, bash, install, permission, script

The installer is getting failed while running the post-install script with error: *** Couldn't posix_spawn: error 2

We are importing the certificate in the post-install script for validation. PublicKey.sh is the post-install script that is executing when running from the terminal but not through the Installer(MyInstaller.dmg).

We have tried the following options by altering PublicKey.sh:

1. Deleted PublicKey.sh file and recreated manually and tried to echo some dummy text.
2. Replaced #!/bin/bash to #!/bin/sh
3. Replaced #!/bin/bash to #!/usr/bin/env bash
4. Removed .sh extension or renamed file.

However, it seems that this file is not getting called from the installer as the echo text is not getting printed in the installer logs. I have attached PublicKey.sh file as well as installer logs to see the error. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image]

Logs :

```
2022-05-02 16:13:00+05:30 Admins-MacBook-Pro package_script_service[795]: Set responsibility to pid: 1044, responsible_path: /System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/Installer
2022-05-02 16:13:00+05:30 Admins-MacBook-Pro package_script_service[795]: PackageKit: *** Couldn't posix_spawn: error 2
2022-05-02 16:13:00+05:30 Admins-MacBook-Pro package_script_service[795]: PackageKit: Failed task attributes: {
        NSFileCreationDate = "2022-05-02 09:30:34 +0000";
        NSFileExtensionHidden = 0;
        NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID = 0;
        NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName = wheel;
        NSFileHFSCreatorCode = 0;
        NSFileHFSTypeCode = 0;
        NSFileModificationDate = "2022-05-02 09:30:34 +0000";
        NSFileOwnerAccountID = 0;
        NSFileOwnerAccountName = root;
        NSFilePosixPermissions = 493;
        NSFileReferenceCount = 1;
        NSFileSize = 497;
        NSFileSystemFileNumber = 12884984619;
        NSFileSystemNumber = 16777220;
        NSFileType = NSFileTypeRegular;
    }
2022-05-02 16:13:00+05:30 Admins-MacBook-Pro package_script_service[795]: Responsibility set back to self.
2022-05-02 16:13:00+05:30 Admins-MacBook-Pro install_monitor[1051]: Re-included: /Applications, /Library, /System, /bin, /private, /sbin, /usr
2022-05-02 16:13:01+05:30 Admins-MacBook-Pro installd[509]: PackageKit: releasing backupd
2022-05-02 16:13:01+05:30 Admins-MacBook-Pro installd[509]: PackageKit: allow user idle system sleep
2022-05-02 16:13:01+05:30 Admins-MacBook-Pro installd[509]: PackageKit: Cleared responsibility for install from 1044.
2022-05-02 16:13:01+05:30 Admins-MacBook-Pro installd[509]: PackageKit: Cleared permissions on Installer.app
2022-05-02 16:13:01+05:30 Admins-MacBook-Pro installd[509]: PackageKit: Install Failed: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package “MyInstaller”." UserInfo={NSFilePath=./postinstall, NSURL=file:///Volumes/MyInstaller%201/MyInstaller.pkg#MyInstaller.pkg, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=com.MyInstaller, NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred while running scripts from the package “MyInstaller”.} {
        NSFilePath = "./postinstall";
        NSLocalizedDescription = "An error occurred while running scripts from the package \U201cMyInstaller\U201d.";
        NSURL = "file:///Volumes/MyInstaller%201/MyInstaller.pkg#MyInstaller.pkg";
        PKInstallPackageIdentifier = "com.MyInstaller";
    }
2022-05-02 16:13:01+05:30 Admins-MacBook-Pro installd[509]: PackageKit: Running idle tasks
2022-05-02 16:13:01+05:30 Admins-MacBook-Pro Installer[1044]: install:didFailWithError:Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package “MyInstaller”." UserInfo={NSFilePath=./postinstall, NSURL=file:///Volumes/MyInstaller%201/MyInstaller.pkg#MyInstaller.pkg, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=com.MyInstaller, NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred while running scripts from the package “MyInstaller”.}
2022-05-02 16:13:01+05:30 Admins-MacBook-Pro installd[509]: PackageKit: Removing client PKInstallDaemonClient pid=1044, uid=501 (/System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/Installer)
2022-05-02 16:13:01+05:30 Admins-MacBook-Pro installd[509]: PackageKit: Done with sandbox removals
2022-05-02 16:13:02+05:30 Admins-MacBook-Pro Installer[1044]: Install failed: The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.
2022-05-02 16:13:02+05:30 Admins-MacBook-Pro Installer[1044]: IFDInstallController 126F820 state = 8
2022-05-02 16:13:02+05:30 Admins-MacBook-Pro Installer[1044]: Displaying 'Install Failed' UI.
```

Comment: pleas paste text as text not images so we can read it and include all the text - I suspect an important piece is missing

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48763315/packagekit-couldnt-posix-spawn-error-2,

Comment: Is the script executable (chmod +x)? Does it run if you run it directly from Terminal?

Comment: Yes, this script is executing from the terminal but not from Installer.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the correct script here?